# Configuring git and apache on solaris box

Tags: git, apache, http, solaris

Does anybody know how to setup git with apache on a solaris 11 box?
I know how to do most things on ubuntu and RHEL/Centos but not solaris. I imagine its fairly similar but having a starting point will be good.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This question is likely too broad for SO, but it's also unclear. What do you mean by "setup git with apache"? Are you trying to install Git and Apache? Or to set up Git on your server so users can push to and pull from it? What have you tried already, and what didn't work?

Comment: This is not a programming question, and should be posted on Server Fault, however you'll likely get a better response if you ask "answerable" questions, including what you've tried before, error messages, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When you mention the two together I suppose you mean exposing your Git repo via http(s) protocol ?

It is very simple. You just use the normal `pkg` command to install the two from Oracle's repo.

### Git

```
# as root or equally permissioned user
pkg install developer/versioning/git
```

### Apache httpd

```
# as root or equally permissioned user
pkg install web/server/apache-22
```

The web server will have its conf files in `/etc/apache2/2.2/` and logs in `/var/apache2/2.2/logs`.

You'll need to have a very basis knowledge about [SMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_Management_Facility) (equivalent on Linux - they really suck in comparision IMO - would be something like `systemd`). By basic knowledge I mean you at least need to know how to stop and start services using SMF. So you start the web server like this `svcadm enable apache22` and stop it like this `svcadm disable apache22`.

Now you'll need Apache Web Server knowledge to [configure your web server with Git](http://www.jedi.be/blog/2009/05/06/8-ways-to-share-your-git-repository/#apachehttp). This will not be Solaris-specific so I won't go into details.

This was a very basic crash course.